# How to embed a PDF viewer on userform for Mac Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macos, pdf, activex

I am developing a VBA userform which contains an ActiveX control - web browser control.

I use this to view the pdf and it runs successfully on my PC.

Mac does not support ActiveX controls but my userform still needs a standard form control to view the pdfs.

Since pdf reader or web browser cannot be used, what is the best alternative control (supported on Mac) to view the pdf?

I thought about inserting an image control, then convert the pdfs into images. Is there a simpler way to achieve this?